# use AWS to transfer and store files in android chatting app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to use AWS to exchange and store files in the Android messaging app between 2 or more users (groupchat).
If the user will send a file, he will upload it to the AWS and send a message to the recipient(s) with information on how to download the attachment (id, file name ?)

Each user should have his own key to limit access to files which he sends/received.
Is this available with some easy setup by S3 for example with the usage of AWSMobileClient on Android app? I am not able to find any useful example.

Comment: I believe aws sdk is never build around this intention, what you can do is get a directory and have efficient poll on it, whenever a A-->sends message to-->B send a silent Push and poll the AWS directory.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware - if you want to use only one instance of S3 and want restrict usage of some files for certain user then I think you need to add extra layer that will handle access to that files. For example - create Lambda for handling access to S3 and use DynamoDB for storing information about each user/file and its accessibility.